# Passing folder name to task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm begginer with Visual Studio Code and I have a question, is it possible to search folder names from tasks.json ? For example I have a directory called unit_tests and in this directory I have some subdirectories containing unit tests (unit_tests/tests_1, unit_tests/tests_2 ...) and in tasks.json I want to call python program which takes as a argument folder name of the unit_tests subdirectory (tests_1 or tests_2 or ...). So for example my tasks.json looks like this:

```
{
  "label": "run selected test",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "python",
  "args": [
    "make_test.py", "${input:test_to_run}"],
  "problemMatcher": []
}
```

and "inputs" section:

```
{
  "type": "pickString",
  "id": "test_to_run",
  "description": "Which test to run",
  "options": ["tests_1"],
  "default": "tests_1"
 }
```

and for "options" I don't want to write all my subdirectories like tests_1, tests_2 and so on becuase when I add new test I must remember to add it also in "options" but I would rather just want to list all my subdirectories in someway as if it were written in "options" without updating them everytime I add something new and choose from there folder name which will be pass to "args" section. Is it possible to do it or maybe I can do it in different way ? In Eclipse for example it's possible to just point to the directory and it will be pass under ${selected_resource_loc}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pick-file)

See the example of using `extension.commandvariable.file.pickFile`